# Jenkins - Trigger a stage if PR request contains a message

Tags: jenkins

How to trigger a stage if the git PR request message has a message `"Please build full pipeline"`?

I want the jenkins build to run every time there is a commit but a certain stage (which triggers another job) needs to be run only if the PR request from feature to master branch has the message `"Please build full pipeline"`...

Whenever the feature branch has a commit the pipeline is build but if a merge request from feature to master with a specific message should trigger a different stage in the pipeline.

Comment: what have you tried so far?